# `make` command not working for all targets specified

Tags: pdf, makefile, latex, dvi

I have to create a make file for building pdf and dvi files separately from 2 tex files.. resume.tex and article tex. What I have made looks like this:

```
 all: resume_all article_all 

 dvi: article_dvi resume_dvi

 pdf: resume_pdf article_pdf

 article_dvi : article.tex 
        latex article.tex
 article_pdf : article.tex ref.bib
        pdflatex article.tex
        bibtex article
        pdflatex article.tex
        pdflatex article.tex

 article_all : article.tex ref.bib
        latex article.tex
        bibtex article
        pdflatex article.tex
        pdflatex article.tex


 resume_dvi : resume.tex
        latex resume.tex

 resume_pdf : resume.tex
        pdflatex resume.tex

 resume_all : resume.tex
        pdflatex resume.tex
        latex resume.tex



 clean:
        rm -f *.log *.bak *.aux *.bbl *.blg *.idx *.toc *.out *~

 clean-all:
        rm -f *.dvi *.log *.bak *.aux *.bbl *.blg *.idx *.ps *.eps *.pdf *.toc *.out *~
```

What happens is when I run `make` on my terminal. Only the pdf for resume.tex is created. Nothing else happens. Same for all other definitions. Only the first target is executed.

Comment: Did only the first target `resume.tex` change?

Comment: I did not change any of the targets.

Comment: IIRC, `make` would only change an output if the target (or dependency) has been modified.

Comment: If you have not modified any of the tex or bib files, then why should Make rebuild anything? (Also, for those of us unfamiliar with latex, pdflatex and bibtex, it would be helpful to explain what those commands do.)

Comment: @Beta. There are no resume_all or article_all target files generated in the rules so make would always try to execute the rule.

Comment: @SagarSakre: I'd guessed that much; I'm asking the OP why he wants/expects Make to do anything.

Comment: @Beta. Well I didn't change even the first target. Why does that get built when I run 'make' from the terminal ?

Comment: @Werner. When I run 'make pdf' for the very first time, both the pdf files should be created, right ? But in my case only the first one i.e resume.pdf is created. What happens to the second target is my exact question?